# Import large csv file to mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql, import-from-csv

I have a very large CSV file (150 MB). What is the best way to import it to MySQL?
I have to do some manipulation in PHP before inserting it into the MySQL table.

Comment: check my solution at http://stackoverflow.com/a/22744300/2037323 which includes some comparisons also

Answer (score 6):

You could take a look at [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) in MySQL.

You might be able to do the manipulations once the data is loaded into MySQL, rather than first reading it into PHP. First store the raw data in a temporary table using LOAD DATA INFILE, then transform the data to the target table using a statement like the following:

```
INSERT INTO targettable (x, y, z)
SELECT foo(x), bar(y), z
FROM temptable
```

Comment: + 1 for LOAD DATA INFILE. If you use phpmyadmin (obviously PHP :) you can easily compare several methods, most popular: SELECT INTO and LOAD DATA INFILE with all their different args and parameters. You will what´s best for you. Most likely it's LOAD DATA INFILE

Comment: Depending on the amount of manipulation he has to do to the data it might be more feasible to read it into php first and insert one row at a time. If the amount of manipulation is significant it is more efficient to do it in a script anyway and then he has two operations. 1. with LOAD DATA INFILE and then 2. with UPDATE TABLE queries.

Answer (score 3):

I would just open it with fopen and use fgetcsv to read each line into an array. 
pseudo-php follows:

```
mysql_connect( //connect to db);

$filehandle = fopen("/path/to/file.csv", "r");
while (($data = fgetcsv($filehandle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    // $data is an array
    // do your parsing here and insert into table
}

fclose($filehandle)
```