# How to copy data from a .txt file to a .sql file or in a database table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, import

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Import large csv file to mysql database using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776192/import-large-csv-file-to-mysql-database-using-php)

**1.** I have a .txt file named **un.txt** in my public_html folder with 4000 usernames arranged like this:

> username1,username2,username3,.....

**2.** and I have a created a table named **oldusernames** in database **members**. The table has only one column named **oldusers**. I'm using MySql.

How can I import all usernames from file **un.txt** to my database(**members**) table(**oldusernames**) in **oldusers** field **using PHP**?

Comment: many more dupes: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=import+csv+file+mysql

Comment: hint: since you dont seem to have rows, the trick will be to use `LINES TERMINATED BY ','`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Steps (remember we shouldn't be expected to write large pieces of code for you):**

1. Load the text file in PHP ([look at PHP's file functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php))
2. Split the string into array elements, delimited by a comma ([look at PHP's explode function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php))
3. Loop through each array element and insert it into the database.

I hope this helps you.